# Porting binary file reading C++ code to C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, binaryfiles

I am trying to port some code from our C++ application to ensure that the licence files are compatible with both applications.

I've tried marking the functions as external, however that opened a whole other can of worms that I wouldn't like to delve into considering this is my last week at my current employer.

The C++ code I'd like to port is as follows:

```
std::fstream licenceFile(filePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
licenceFile.read((char *) &this->m_FileData, sizeof(this->m_FileData));
```

m_FileData is a struct and is as follows:

```
struct LicManKeyFileData
{
    BYTE m_EncryptedKey[255];
    WCHAR m_MacAddress[33];
    WCHAR m_PreviousMacLicense[33];
    WCHAR m_SoftwareName[16];
    WCHAR m_ClientName[65];
    BYTE m_Version;
    BYTE m_EncryptionLength;
    time_t m_LicenseTime;
};
```

I have tried several methods of replicating this in C#, firstly reading the file member by member, for example:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(licenceFileStream, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);

licenceFileData.EncryptedKey = reader.ReadBytes(licenceFileData.EncryptedKey.Length);

byte[] mac = new byte[sizeof(char) * licenceFileData.MacAddress.Length];
mac = reader.ReadBytes(mac.Length);
```

Something strange I noticed about this method is that a lot of the values were being set as 204 seemingly arbitrarily, when they are read correctly in the C++ application, so I've had to add this:

```
if (mac[0] == 204)
    mac[0] = 0;
```

Which makes no sense to me, it's not an alignment issue, reading from a byte before or after that gives totally garbage values (chinese characters) and this check and assigning 0 to the first index allows me to get the proper value.

Another method I've tried was found on here on StackOverflow, and is as follows:

```
 public static T ReadStruct<T>(this BinaryReader reader) where T : struct
 {
     Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))];
     reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     GCHandle handle = default(GCHandle);

     try
     {
        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
     }
     finally
     {
        if (handle.IsAllocated)
            handle.Free();
     }
 }
```

Oddly, this method also returns some values as 204 where the C++ application reads them as the correct value.

The struct I'm using in C# looks like this:

```
unsafe struct LicenceFileDataS
{
    internal fixed byte m_EncryptedKey[255];
    internal fixed char m_MacAddress[33];
    internal fixed char m_PreviousMacLicense[33];
    internal fixed char m_SoftwareName[16];
    internal fixed char m_ClientName[65];
    internal byte m_Version;
    internal byte m_EncryptionLength;
    internal long m_LicenseTime;
}
```

Does anyone know a better method for porting this code or how I can fix the values that are being read as 204? It works perfectly in C++. My apologies for the wall of text.

Comment: What is the correct value that the C++ version reads? Can you post a line or 2 of the bytes read from each also?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII for example, the mac address byte array would be 
mac[0] = 204
mac[1] = 48 in C#, but in C++
mac[0] = 0
mac[1] = 48

Comment: @bommelding Yes, they're both 560 bytes. And re. the atttributes, would the Offset attribute be useful here?

Comment: And are you certain of the encoding?  I'm just speculating because I don't know either why you would get a 204 instead of 0.  I'm only guessing that maybe it has something to do with the encoding. I'm curious when you find the answer.

Comment: @bommelding yes, the file viewed in a hex editor shows lots of 0xCC, including just prior to the mac address. I'm not sure what could be causing it though, the files still manage to be read by the licence manager that created them. Do you think it could be anything to do with the licence being created with the debug version of the manager?